Macro doesn't work: unexpected behavior of if-then-else statement
I'm encountering an issue with my LaTeX macro designed to create a glossary. The intention is to generate sections for each new letter of the alphabet and subsections for terms starting with the same letter. However, the macro is only displaying the first section (for example letter A if the glossary starts with an A).
% package
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{datatool}

% my macro
\newcommand{\createGlossary}[2]{
    % Load data from CSV file using the specified separator
    \DTLsetseparator{#1}
    \DTLloaddb{glossary}{#2}
    % Sort data alphabetically based on the term
    \DTLsort{termine}{glossary}
    % Variables to track the current and previous letters
    \newcommand{\current}{}
    \newcommand{\previous}{}
    % Iterate over the data to create sections and subsections
    \DTLforeach{glossary}{\term=termine,\description=descrizione}{%
        % Extract the first letter of the term
        \StrLeft{\term}{1}[\current]\par
        
        \typeout{Current: \current}
        \typeout{Previous: \previous}
        
        \IfStrEq{\current}{\previous}{
            \subsection*{\term}
            \description
        }{
            \section*{\current}
            \renewcommand{\previous}{\current}
        }\par
    }
}

Despite following a similar logic to this my Python code provided below, where the logic works correctly, the LaTeX macro fails.
def print_names(name_list):
    previous_initial = ''
    for name in name_list:
        if name[0] != previous_initial:
            print(name[0])
            previous_initial = name[0]
        print(name)

names = ["Anna", "Giacomo", "Giovanni", "Luigi", "Marco", "Mario", "Paolo"]
print_names(names)


Example Usage
\createGlossary{,}{glossary.csv}

Replace glossary.csv with the path to your CSV file containing the glossary data, and adjust the separator if necessary.
Issue Analysis
The issue seems to stem from the fact that the \createGlossary macro behaves as if the 'previous' and 'current' variables are always equal, preventing the creation of new sections beyond the first letter of the alphabet. This is in fact my debug output:
Current: A
Previous: 
Current: A
Previous: A
Current: A
Previous: A
Current: B
Previous: B
Current: B
Previous: B
Current: B
Previous: B
Current: B
Previous: B
Current: B
Previous: B
...


If anyone has insights or suggestions on how to debug and fix the \createGlossary macro, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Please, add an example of glossary.csv: you know what it contains, we don't.

After \renewcommand{\previous}{\current} expanding the token \previous yields the token \current so that total expansion of \previous always is the same as total expansion of \current and therefore the \IfStrEq-test always yields the branch for the case of strings being equal.
Instead of \renewcommand{\previous}{\current} you need to do \let\previous=\current.
Besides this,

there is the environment description whose underlying command is \description. In order not to override that command prefixing the names of all internal helper macros defined in your code with "my" is done. For real life scenario using a better namespace prefix is suggested. Maybe the overriding is/would be restricted to a local scope opened by \DTLforeach, but the author of the initial release of this answer is not sure if this is the case.
after tokenizing { or } the reading-apparatus of TeX is in state M (middle of line). When the reading apparatus is in state M while encountering an end of a line, the end of that line usually/under normal circumstances yields insertion of a space token into the token stream which in turn may yield visible horizontal space in case TeX currently is typesetting things in horizontal mode when processing it.
So comment characters %%% were inserted here and there for avoiding the coming into being of unwanted/unneeded space tokens.
\section* and \subsection* usually start a new paragraph after the heading, so inserting tokens \par seems obsolete.

\newcommand\myprevious{}%
\newcommand\mycurrent{}%
\newcommand{\createGlossary}[2]{%%%
    % Load data from CSV file using the specified separator
    \DTLsetseparator{#1}%%%
    \DTLloaddb{glossary}{#2}%%%
    % Sort data alphabetically based on the term
    \DTLsort{termine}{glossary}%%%
    % Variables to track the current and previous letters
    \gdef\mycurrent{}%%%
    \gdef\myprevious{}%%%
    % Iterate over the data to create sections and subsections
    \DTLforeach{glossary}{\myterm=termine,\mydescription=descrizione}{%
        % Extract the first letter of the term
        \StrLeft{\myterm}{1}[\mycurrent]%%%
        \typeout{Current: \mycurrent}%%%
        \typeout{Previous: \myprevious}%%%
        %\par        
        \IfStrEq{\mycurrent}{\myprevious}{}{%%%
            \section*{\mycurrent}%%%
            \global\let\myprevious=\mycurrent
        }%%%
        \subsection*{\myterm}%%%
        \mydescription
        %\par
    }%%%
}%%%

